# What's the expected delay for update propagation in the Google Sheet API?

Tags: google-sheets-api

In general, for our usage of the Google Sheet API, the data appears to be eventually consistent-- that is, updates in the UI (Chrome) take some time to be reflected when the sheet is read via the API.  In some instances, this delay is roughly half an hour.

I was just wondering if there's an expected or maximum value for this delay or if it's just "best effort".

---

I've found [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40546) question that mentions eventual consistency with the Sheet API, but that's about it.

I'm using version 4 of the Java API to access the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Google Docs documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en):

> Functions that pull data from outside the spreadsheet recalculate at the following times:
>
> - ImportRange: 30 minutes
> - ImportHtml, ImportFeed, ImportData, ImportXml: 1 hour
> - GoogleFinance: may be delayed up to 20 minutes

It turns out that the issue reported by the user dealt with roughly a half-hour delay with the `ImportRange` function.